# How to use macros to save a document with password via the "file > save as" dialog?

Tags: vba, ms-word, password-protection

I created a Word template with some VBA macro to prompt the user to enter a password. This password should then be used to encrypt the new document created from the template.

The startup code is properly executed and also the user form works as expected.
I'm able to "[only set a password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.password)" but the [dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.dialogs) for the "file > save as" function with the enum [`wdDialogFileSaveAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdworddialog) does not seem to work as it is said in the official documentation.

**So the question is:** how to use a macro to open a save dialog for saving a document with password encryption turned on for a given password?

### Startup Code

This is the startup code, when creating a new document from the Word template:

```vb
'in TemplateProject > Microsoft Word Objects > ThisDocument
Private Sub Document_New()
    DialogSetPassword.Show
End Sub
```

### User Form

The user form `DialogSetPassword` looks like this:

[image: password prompt]

### Password Code

The code to either set a password only or directly save the document with a password looks like this:

```vb
'in TemplateProject > Forms > DialogSetPassword
Private Sub ButtonOnlySetPassword_Click()
    ActiveDocument.password = TextBoxPassword.Text
    MsgBox "Password successfully set"
    'Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonSaveWithPassword_Click()
    MsgBox "Password is " & TextBoxPassword.Text  'just for debug reasons to see if the password is properly read
    'ActiveDocument.password = TextBoxPassword.Text  'it works when this line is present, then the password field is pre-filled
    With Application.Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
        .Name = ThisDocument.FullName  'name of the template
        .Format = wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled  'saving as macro enabled document, as there are more macros
        .password = TextBoxPassword.Text
        .Show
    End With
    'Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub TextBoxPassword_Change()
    If Len(TextBoxPassword.Text) = 0 Then
        ButtonOnlySetPassword.Enabled = False
        ButtonSaveWithPassword.Enabled = False
    Else
        ButtonOnlySetPassword.Enabled = True
        ButtonSaveWithPassword.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

According to the documentation, parameters like `Name, Format, Password` should be accepted by the function, but the password option does not work.

### Save Dialog

Even when using the dialog function with the `.password` parameter, the password field in the save dialog is still empty (can be found under "Save As > Tools > General Options > Password to Open"):

[image: save dialog]

Comment: "`'ActiveDocument.password = TextBoxPassword.Text  'it works when this line is present, then the password field is pre-filled`" - As you already have the answer, why are you asking the question?

Comment: @TimothyRylatt because I'm still learning VBA and I want to understand what I'm doing wrong here. According to the documentation the `.password` parameter in the dialog function should be sufficient to save a document with a password. But as it does not work, I want to find out how the correct use of that function would look like - without using my workaround. Further, when the user cancels the "save as" dialog, the password is now still set on the document which kinda feels like a side effect to me.

Comment: You're not  doing anything wrong. The VBA documentation isn't always correct, and the code examples it contains don't always work. What you describe as a workaround is the correct way to set a password. If you're concerned that the user is going to cancel you could use [`.Display`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.dialog.display) instead of `.Show`. You would then only use the dialog to capture the user's choices and would need to use the `SaveAs` method to save the document.

Comment: I should have refreshed my memory before writing the last comment. You can, of course, use the return value of `.Show` to check if the user cancelled, and then delete the password from the document.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt but why is then there even a `.password` parameter if it's not used at all?
Could you please provide an example with that workaround of how to use the `.Show` return value as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation simply lists the parameters of the dialog and gives no details of whether they are read/write or read only. If you use the `.Display` method, you will find that `.Password` is read only.

Both the `.Display` and `.Show` methods of a dialog return a value, as Long, to indicate the user's action. To use the return value, you call these methods in the same way as for any other function, i.e. `.Display()` and `.Show()`

Below is a reworking of your code.

```
Private Sub ButtonSaveWithPassword_Click()
    Dim ret As Long
    ActiveDocument.Password = TextBoxPassword.Text
    With Application.Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
        .Name = ThisDocument.FullName  'name of the template
        .Format = wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled  'saving as macro enabled document, as there are more macros
        ret = .Show()
        If ret = 0 Then ActiveDocument.Password = vbNullString  'user cancelled save as dialog
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Where did you find the information about the `.password` being read-only?

Comment: @winklerrr - Through trying it.